# Copying preloaded database, adding carriage returns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-2.2-froyo

I have an app which comes with a preloaded database.

My temporary copy function is like so

```
private void copyDatabase() {

    AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(DATABASE_NAME);
        out = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_FILE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if(in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However on Android 2.2 I keep getting an error "database disk image malformed". So I went ahead and copied it off the device, onto my computer. And sure enough, it wouldn't open. I did a hex compare on the two files and there are 10 instances where 1 byte is different. Hex 0D has been added 10 times in random spots in the malformed copy.
The copy routine works fine in 3.x+. I also have developed other apps with the same method and don't have an issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using SQLiteAssetHelper https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper - if you ZIP or GZIP the database as per the instructions, it will prevent DB corruption with Android versions less than API 10 and it also does all the 'heavy lifting' with respect to database copying and upgrading.

Comment: Well This is odd. I recreated my preload database using exact same data, and now error doesn't occur, and copies fine.

Comment: This sounds as if the file was copied in ASCII (text) mode over FTP.

Comment: Your code is ok and i could not believe your issue. `Hex 0D has been added 10 times in random spots in the malformed copy`. Did you not find them next to a 0x0A?

Comment: @greenapps yes they were next to 0X0A, but I dont know why android should be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was, but I created a new sqlite database, imported the data, and that seemed to work.